# Odoo 12 installation fails due to python setup.py install

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-18.04, odoo-12

I am trying to install Odoo 12 in Ubuntu 18. There is an official document here:- https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-12-on-ubuntu-18-04/
There are many steps. All succeed except the following:-

When I run the command as `python setup.py install`

it gives an error:-

```
root@ip-172-31-45-49:/opt/odoo/gdata-2.0.18# python setup.py install
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata-2.0.18.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata-2.0.18.egg-info
```

Can anybody suggest what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you're running Python 2.7 and you need Python 3

Comment: I could go far by python3 setup.py install. But gdata-2.0.18 is giving SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Like ile "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 660
    except gdata.service.RequestError, e: I have no knowledge of python. So i can't fix it.  I got it as wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/a8/70/bd554151443fe9e89d9a934a7891aaffc63b9cb5c7d608972919a002c03c/gdata-2.0.18.tar.gz. There should be tested release version of gdata.

Comment: Try skipping step 8